# How do I find $f(4)$ when $f(n)= f(n-1)+ 2n$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can somebody please help me find $f(4)$ when $f(n)= f(n-1)+ 2n$? $f(1)$ equals $16$ by the way.

Comment: It's a recursive formula so start out calculating $f(2)$ using $f(1)$ and then move on to 3 and 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
f(4) &= \color{blue}{f(3)} + 2\cdot 4 \\
&= \color{blue}{(f(2) + 2\cdot 3)} + 2\cdot 4 \\
&= \dots 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @user152559: no problem.

Comment: Ouch, it seems the downvote is mine. It must have been a missclick, and I haven't noticed it before. It's too old to remove, but if you could make some minor edit, I'd be happy to rectify this. Sorry for that!

Comment: @MarcinŁoś: No problem. All forgiven. I edited.

Comment: Great - thanks, changed to +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can even find $f(n)$ for every $n$: in fact by telescoping
$$f(n)-f(1)=\sum_{k=2}^n(f(k)-f(k-1))=\sum_{k=2}^n2k=(n+2)(n-1)$$
so
$$f(n)=16+(n+2)(n-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

You could write $f(n)=g(n)+n^2-n$ if you are looking for a general solution. For $f(4)$, just compute

Answer (score 0):

$f(4)=f(3)+8$

$f(3)=f(2)+6$

$f(2)=f(1)+4$

$f(1)=16$

Sum all these and cancel to get $f(4)=8+6+4+16$.